# How do I index already existing objects in Riak

Tags: riak, riak-search

I created a bucket in riak and stored some key value pairs (value being a json object). After this I ran `/usr/sbin/search-cmd install <bucket>` to start riak search for the bucket.

Each object has a 'type' attribute and I am trying to search objects of particular type using `/usr/sbin/search-cmd search <bucket> "type:xyz"` but I get the following error:

```
RPC to 'riak@127.0.0.1' failed: {'EXIT',
                             {badarg,
                              [{ets,lookup,
                                [schema_table,<<"catalog">>],
                                []},
                               {riak_search_config,get_schema,1,
                                [{file,"src/riak_search_config.erl"},
                                 {line,69}]},
                               {riak_search_client,parse_query,3,
                                [{file,"src/riak_search_client.erl"},
                                 {line,57}]},
                               {search,search,3,
                                [{file,"src/search.erl"},{line,55}]},
                               {riak_search_cmd,search,3,
                                [{file,"src/riak_search_cmd.erl"},
                                 {line,188}]},
                               {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                                [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,203}]}]}}
```

I read that indexing happens through a pre-commit hook so I also POSTed all objects again but still no results. Am I missing any step in setting up riak search?

Answer (score 0):

Figured that riak search was not enabled in my app.config.